# How to redirect page after Image slider finish loading in jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins

I have a site with a rotating banner image in intro div and rest of the home page in page div. I want to do the following:

1. How can we hide intro div which contains current rotating banner images after finishing last slide and show rest of the home page.
2. Or if user will click on skip intro text then also it will show home page.

Current site: http://new.brandonplanning.com/home

I think modification is required in this code

```js
/*-------------Intro page slider starts-----------*/

var intervalID;

function slideSwitch() {
    var $active = $('#slideshow IMG.active');

    if ($active.length == 0) $active = $('#slideshow IMG:last');

    //var $next = $active.next().length ? $active.next()
    //    : $('#slideshow IMG:first');

    var $next;
    if ($active.next().length) {
        $next = $active.next().delay(3000);
    } else {
        clearInterval(intervalID);
        visibilityCheck();
        return;
    }

    $active.addClass('last-active');

    $next.css({ opacity: 0.0 })
        .addClass('active')
        .animate({ opacity: 1.0 }, 1000, function () {
            $active.removeClass('active last-active');
        });
}

$(function () {
    intervalID = setInterval("slideSwitch()", 6000);
});

/*-------------Intro page slider ends-----------*/

/*-------------Intro page skip starts-----------*/

$(window).load(function () {
    $(function () {
        visibilityCheck();
        $('#loader').remove();
    });

    $('.skip-intro').click(function () {
        visibilityCheck();
    });
});

function visibilityCheck() {
    $('.hidden').removeClass('hidden');

    if ($('#page').is(':hidden')) {
        $('#intro').addClass('hidden');
    } else {
        $('#page').addClass('hidden');
    }
}

/*-------------Intro page skip ends-----------*/
```

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically what you need is this:

### *[demo jsBin](http://jsbin.com/uwujel/edit#javascript,html,live)*

```
$('#slider img:gt(0)').hide();

var T; // timeout
var c = 0;  // counter
var imgN = $('#slider img').length; // get the images Number

function toggler(){    // screens toggler function
  $('#intro').fadeTo(400,0).siblings('#page').fadeTo(400,1);
}

function a(){  // 'A'nimations
  if(c === imgN ){   // if the 'C'ounter reached the images in slider...
    toggler();       // toggle our screens
  }else{             // else ... do our animations.
    $('#slider img').siblings('img').stop().fadeTo(1000,0).eq(c++).stop().fadeTo(1000,1);
  }                                                        // ^^^^ here the counter 'ticks'
}

function aa(){ // 'A'uto 'A'dvance
   T=setTimeout(function(){
       a();
       aa();
   },2000);     // set here pause between slides
}
aa();


$('#skip').click(function(){  // if 'skip' is clicked...
  clearTimeout(T);                 // well...
  toggler();                       // run our screens 'toggler'
});
```

Hope you'll easily implement this into your page.

Comment: Thanks for your Reply Roko, Its causing problem in IE8 last image remains or visible behind home page

Comment: I want the same thing but its causing js error IE8 dont know how error is for $(#skip).on id

Comment: Can you help me out for IE 8 browser what i have tried is working fine but dont know why it is not working in IE8, its not showing image slider? http://new.brandonplanning.com/home

Comment: Thanks a lot Roko, yesterday was my first day on stack overflow and i found this very usefull. Thanks once again :)

Answer (score 1):

> 1, How can we hide intro div which contains current rotating banner images after finishing last slide and show rest of the home page.

You'll need to check that the last image has the `.active`, then use `.delay()` before hiding the `#intro` and showing the `#page`, something like:

```
if ($(.skip-intro li).last().hasClass('active')){
  $('#intro').delay(2000).addClass('.hidden').queue(function() {
    $('#page').removeClass('.hidden');
  });
}
```

> 2,  Or if user will click on skip intro text then also it will show home page.

```
$('.skip-intro').click(function(){
  $('#intro').addClass('.hidden');
  $('#page').removeClass('.hidden');
});
```

Comment: Thanks for Reply Alex But the main thing is that i am using hidden class to show and hide intro and page div. My requirement is simple first on page load all images will load then slider will start working and after finishing last slide it will show page div and hide intro div

Comment: amended my answer to use `add/removeClass` instead of `.show()/.hide()`

Comment: Thanks a lot Alex you make my day really i was stuck with this from last 2 days.

Thanks Again

Comment: Hi Alex
It is working fine in all browsers but in IE 8 My loader image will appear late and then it show my home page i am not able to view slider please could you suggest